# better way to create a new column instead of for loop

Tags: python, pandas, performance, for-loop

is there any faster way to this code?
i just want to calculate t_last - t_i and create a new column

```
time_ges = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0, len(df.GesamteMessung_Sec.index), 1):
    time = df.GesamteMessung_Sec.iloc[-1]-df.GesamteMessung_Sec.iloc[i]
    time_ges = time_ges.append(pd.DataFrame({'echte_Ladezeit': time}, index=[0]), ignore_index=True)

df['echte_Ladezeit'] = time_ges
```

this code takes a lot of computation time, is there any better way to do this?
thanks, R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subtract last value by column `GesamteMessung_Sec` and add [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) for convert `Series` to `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'GesamteMessung_Sec':[10,2,1,5]})
print (df)
   GesamteMessung_Sec
0                  10
1                   2
2                   1
3                   5

time_ges = (df.GesamteMessung_Sec.iloc[-1] - df.GesamteMessung_Sec).to_frame('echte_Ladezeit')
print (time_ges )
   echte_Ladezeit
0              -5
1               3
2               4
3               0
```

If need new column of original DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'GesamteMessung_Sec':[10,2,1,5]})
df['echte_Ladezeit'] = df.GesamteMessung_Sec.iloc[-1] - df.GesamteMessung_Sec
print (df)
   GesamteMessung_Sec  echte_Ladezeit
0                  10              -5
1                   2               3
2                   1               4
3                   5               0
```